# Mac addresses of devices on network

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, osx-mavericks

I'm on OSX Mavericks. I'm connected via wifi to my network. How can I find the mac addresses of all other devices on the network?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `nmap` to do a scan of the network.

`nmap -sn 192.168.0.0/24` <-- replace the subnet with your own.

You can get nmap from [here](http://nmap.org/book/inst-macosx.html)

Alternatively, a GUI tool is `fing` which can be grabbed from [here](http://www.overlooksoft.com/download)

Does much the same job - however apparently only works for Snow Leopard, Lion, and Mountain Lion.

Comment: On your local network, an ARP scan is also useful: `nmap -PR 192.168.0.0/24` Additionally - a passive tool such as kismet can listen for active MACs on a wifi network without actively scanning.

Comment: `nmap` doesn't seem to work out of the box on a Mac... hm

Comment: If it would work, nmap is the right answer here. An ip scanning tool would probably also make sure the arp table is up to date.

Comment: Yeah, IP Scan the network, and then check the ARP table would also give you the same results of nmap. Unfortunately I'm not too familiar with Macs so I don't know of any ping scanners for Mac.

Answer (score 0):

On some routers, there is an option to view clients connected to the router, and it may display the addresses. I've got a Linksys EA2700 that does this, under `DHCP Client Table`. This may vary from router to router of course, but a viable option.

[image]

Comment: Worth noting is that the DHCP table won't list any clients with a static IP address. Some routers also let you view an ARP table (I believe dd-wrt does), but this has its own caveat: it only works for IPs that have recently been queried for. Scanning is the only true on-demand answer.

Comment: @Bob Of course, scanning is the best method, just a second option :) DD-WRT is preferable as well. This would be on the low-tech end of things.